# How would I deal with installing Pergo without baseboard molding in one area?

Tags: flooring, engineered-flooring

One of the sections of my floor runs alongside a stair railing and then a small raised tile area that used to be where my former wood stove sat.  All told, this is about 15 feet long and then a 90 degree turn and about 4 more feet.

The carpet is just tacked down at the edge of both places and there is no vertical wall or molding there.  Currently the carpet is even with the top of the tile.  I'm actually not sure where the new Pergo would sit vertically relative to this other than to say we have some in the foyer adjacent the carpet area to be upgraded and it's essentially even.

How would I deal with these areas?  Is there some sort of cleat or flush edge molding you can install?

Thanks,

DL